# Android setShareIntent within fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewpager, shareactionprovider

**1. Background**

I have a screen that has a

```
ShareActionProvider
```

and a

```
ViewPager
```

that uses fragments.

What I was hoping to do was get some information from inside the currently visible fragment to create an intent, I would then be able to set the intent on the ShareActionProvider.

This is the code I use to set the intent of the ShareActionProvider:

```
    MenuItem actionItem = men.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
    ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
    actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent(mProduct.mProduct));
```

I have tried using this in several places such as within these functions of the Fragment class :

```
onCreateView
onStart
```

I have also tried using it in these functions within the FragmentPagerAdapter class :

```
getItem
```

**2. The Problem**

Although the intent is actually getting set within the ShareActionProvider, the information that is obtained is for the next fragment (the one not currently being shown). For example:

If I have 4 fragments : frag1, frag2, frag3, frag4
and I am currently viewing "frag1" the ShareActionProvider will attempt to share "frag2". This is true until it reaches "frag4" where it will share the correct value.

My guess is that the fragment pager creates the current view and the next view (hidden), which is in turn setting the ShareActionProvider. If this is the case then where is the correct place to "setShareIntent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to do this myself. What I ended up doing is overriding the

```
OnPageChangeListener
```

in the fragmentactivity

```
private final OnPageChangeListener mOnPageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TestFragment frag = (TestFragment) adapter.mFragments.get(pager.getCurrentItem());

        frag.setShareActionIntent();

    }

};
```

Comment: I'm also having some issues with Fragments and the ShareActionProvider, would you mind sharing your setShareActionIntent() method? Here is my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085905/using-shareactionprovider-from-a-fragment

Comment: Apologies for not getting back sooner, I've been on holiday! are you still having issues with this? Your question does not seem to be there anymore!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I deleted the question for some reason I have now forgotten. Anyway, I have it working as it should... whatever it was :P

Comment: I have already done the same thing but I have still problem. My app is sharing photos. And I am copying the jpeg file to somewhere to share it. Copying it every time viewpager has changed is not a good way. How can I do it only when the user actually click the share button.

Comment: You should not store references to your fragments in the adapter since these usually got reused

Answer (score 4):

I stumble on this question while dealing with similar problem. 2 things about accepted solution:

1. Don't save reference to the fragment anywhere, especially in some list in the adapter
2. Don't create fields in the fragment, always store data you need in the Bundle so you can get it by using Fragment#getArguments

Now - with this in mind here's a simple solution: put your ShareActionProvider initialization code to `onPrepareOptionsMenu` call. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem menuShare = menu.findItem(R.id.menuShare);
    ShareActionProvider shareAction = (ShareActionProvider) 
         menuShare.getActionProvider();
    shareAction.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
}

protected Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    Job job = getArguments().getSerializable(JOB);
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, job.title);
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, job.toText());
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Comment: how can i share image using share intent in fragment?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html

the example from android sdk doc is:

```
  // In Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Get the menu item.
      MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_item);
      // Get the provider and hold onto it to set/change the share intent.
      mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
      // Set history different from the default before getting the action
      // view since a call to MenuItem.getActionView() calls
      // onCreateActionView() which uses the backing file name. Omit this
      // line if using the default share history file is desired.
      mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName("custom_share_history.xml");
      . . .
  }

  // Somewhere in the application.
  public void doShare(Intent shareIntent) {
      // When you want to share set the share intent.
      mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  }
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing but, I don't know where to set the intent to get the right value