# ShareActionProvider - setShareIntent for drawing application

Tags: android

I'm developing a drawing application and I want to allow user to share his drawings within email, social networks, etc. I know, there is a **ShareActionProvider** class, but there is a one big problem with it.

Content of my application updates rapidly, so I'm not able to call `setShareIntent()` every time user starts or ends drawing. It's obvious, that intent should be created when user press on share button. But, unfortunately, there is no on click listeners or something like that. And that is a problem.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer has no solution, I rate this task impossible without fully rolling your own.**

I totally agree, it should pull the data using a listener when it's required, but at the same time it works this way because it shows only the apps that can handle the intent.

It means that you have to provide the intent before being able to share it, to let the [`<intent-filter>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)s do their thing and filter the incompatible activities. The problem comes when the filter contains a [`<data>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) element which filters the Uri and MimeType.

Let's try to work around this.

### Use OnShareTargetSelectedListener

[@hannes arch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14583997/253468) was on to something, but the answer is missing from the answer which would be `doSomeStuff`'s implementation.

Ah it returns boolean, let's update the intent and do a `startActivity(intent)` and return `true` to signify we handled it.
It turns out that `ShareActivityChooserModelPolicy` ignores the return value of `onShareTargetSelected`, so we can't use that.

Doing so kind of works, but it'll open to of the same activities with different content (the original intent and the modified one). Not so kind to the user.

### Extend `ShareActionProvider`

and replicate logic needed for `ShareActivityChooserModelPolicy` and return the value returned from the listener. This way our `return true` would work. Instead it doesn't. We lose the ability to have history  of selected apps.

### Extend `ShareActionProvider` take 2

I tried and tried, there's just no possible way to extends this class, even with nasty reflection and `setAccessible` calls. It's too rigid.

### Copy `ShareActionProvider`

and related classes. Nope, it won't work it has some Android internal class depedencies.

### Closing words

I just wonder what

> the behavior is extensible and extensions of ShareActionProvider can perform different behaviors and ranking based on the history file (if appropriate).

means from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 4):

Add an action bar to your application.

Then you can add a "Share" icon in the action bar:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" ... />
```

and

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_share:
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      intent.setType("image/jpeg");
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject text");
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Detailed description");
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getPubliclyAccessibleUriOfAnImage());
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share my dynamic image"));
      return true;
```

Using a MENU item could be another solution, but it is not very trendy.

Comment: I'm using this solution. But recommended way is to use ShareActionProvider, which is not really suitable for my purpouses.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

    MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mymenu_item);
    ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
    actionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);       actionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {

    public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                Intent intent) {
            doSomeStuff();//TODO
            return false;
    }} );
    actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    MenuItem overflowItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mymenu_item);
    ShareActionProvider overflowProvider = (ShareActionProvider) overflowItem.getActionProvider();
    overflowProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
    overflowProvider.onPerformDefaultAction();
    overflowProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue with a android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity derivative (though I think this approach should work for any activity) and I overrode onPrepareOptionsMenu and got the effect you are after:

```
private ShareActionProvider actionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

    // get the share menu item
    MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share_menu_item);
    actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();

    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (actionProvider != null) {
        actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    // ripped from @nicolas-raoul answer
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Detailed description");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getPubliclyAccessibleUriOfAnImage());
    return intent;
}
```

See also: [Android setShareIntent within fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362120/android-setshareintent-within-fragment)