# SetShareIntent when a new fragment is displayed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-sharing

My question is similar to [Android setShareIntent within fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362120/android-setshareintent-within-fragment), but I read the answers there and couldn't figure out how to apply them to my situation.

**Quick summary of my question**

I'd like to setShareIntent each time the fragment changes, i.e. whenever a new fragment is shown to the user.  How can I do that?  Where should the setShareIntent call go?

**Longer version with code snippets**

Here's a skeleton of my code:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class SolvePuzzle extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    static AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    static ViewPager mViewPager;

    ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Then comes

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.solve_puzzle, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        if (mShareActionProvider == null) {
            // Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358510/why-menuitemcompat-getactionprovider-returns-null
            mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(this);
            MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, mShareActionProvider);

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text");  // For debugging
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            setShareIntent(shareIntent);

            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Called new mShareActionProvider(this) and set share intent");
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        // Want to call this whenever new puzzle fragment is displayed
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        } else {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Could not set share intent:  mShareActionProvider == null");
        }
    }
```

I then have a `public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter` and a `public class SolvePuzzleFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener`.

Currently I call setShareIntent in the onCreateView of SolvePuzzleFragment.

That doesn't work:  when I look at my logcat, I see that the setShareIntent call coming from the fragments (first two lines) happens before the onCreateOptionsMenu call from the SolvePuzzle class (last line):

> 12-12 12:39:26.505: D/Debug(3864): Could not set share intent: 
>   mShareActionProvider == null
>
> 12-12 12:39:26.515: D/Debug(3864): Could not set share intent: 
>   mShareActionProvider == null
>
> 12-12 12:39:26.565: D/Debug(3864): Called new
>   mShareActionProvider(this) and set share intent

...and it looks like there are two calls from the fragments. Is that because both the current fragment and the next one in line are created (have their onCreateView called), even though only the first one is being displayed?

It looks like calling setShareIntent in the fragment's onCreateView is a mistake.  What I want to do is call setShareIntent when a new fragment is displayed to the user.  How do I do that?

Edit: Additional information:

The share button currently works, but it sends the "Some text" message that I set for debugging purposes in onCreateOptionsMenu. I'd like that intent to be overwritten by a fragment-related intent as soon as the first fragment is displayed to the user (and overwritten each time a new fragment is displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that? Where should the setShareIntent call go?

[Register an `OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) with your `ViewPager` [via `setOnPageChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) and put your `setShareIntent()` call in `onPageSelected()` of the listener.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  My only comment, in case someone else has the same problem and is reading this:  I had to add a special case for the very first fragment which is loaded. Presumably the first fragment to be loaded does not trigger a page change.

Comment: @Adrian: Correct -- I had assumed that you were setting an initial share `Intent` and were only worried about how to implement the change in that `Intent` based upon page change.